# First Come First Serve Multiprocessor (6 processors) scheduler in C code

Tags: c, algorithm, cpu, scheduling, multiprocessor

I am developing for a FCFS scheduler algorithm.  But it only works with one processor.  How can divide the task into 6 processors? I would need waiting queue, ready queue, etc.

Each processor should work individually, if one processor finishes its task, then it would take the next task without waiting for all the processors to finish.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n,bt[20],wt[20],tat[20],avwt=0,avtat=0,i,j;
    printf("Enter total number of processes(maximum 20):");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nEnter Process Burst Time\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("P[%d]:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&bt[i]);
    }

    wt[0]=0;    //waiting time for first process is 0

    //calculating waiting time
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        wt[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            wt[i]+=bt[j];
    }

    printf("\nProcess\t\tBurst Time\tWaiting Time\tTurnaround Time");

    //calculating turnaround time
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        tat[i]=bt[i]+wt[i];
        avwt+=wt[i];
        avtat+=tat[i];
        printf("\nP[%d]\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d",i+1,bt[i],wt[i],tat[i]);
    }

    avwt/=i;
    avtat/=i;
    printf("\n\nAverage Waiting Time:%d",avwt);
    printf("\nAverage Turnaround Time:%d",avtat);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there an operating system involved?  For example, how does `printf()` produce output on a terminal?

Comment: i suggest you use multithreading!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check [ask] for information about how to get the most out of your questions.  For example, this question seems to be a bit broad in scope as you are asking about how to implement basically a whole library.  Try to narrow down to a specific question that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: yes, i am using ubuntu to compile my code,

Comment: how do I implement multithreading in this example, can you please help me? can you please use multithread to demonstrate 4 processors for example?

Comment: There are several ways to do it.  One is to use [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) and create a new process.  Another way is to use [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).  What is it you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework for Operating Systems class.

Since you don't have arrival times of the precesses, only duration, we assume that all arrive at the same time, but are ordered in some list.

I will use the terms jobs and CPUs, instead processes and processors for obvious reasons.

The first six jobs will be assinged to all six CPUs.
The next job (7th) will get assigned to the CPU that will finish first.
Then the next 8th job will be assigned to the CPU that will finish next (after the 7th was started).

The algorithm can be easily implemented with priority (min) queue.

```
p := new priority queue
for 1 to 6
    insert 0 in p

total_wait_time = 0

for j in jobs
    top := pop from p
    end_time := top + j
    total_wait_time += top
    insert end_time in p

avg_wait = total_wait_time / num_of_jobs
```

You can play around with this, maybe to get average finishing times instead of average waiting times.